# How to apply a complex mesh object (in a plane) over rounded/curved surface without distorting beyond recognition

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

Sorry, if it has been asked before, however, I tried my best to search on the forum but was unable to find the right solution.

I am new to Blender and 3D art so please forgive me if I am short of the right tech word or the terminologies.

So, I have created an embossed Harley Davidson Badge mesh (in a ZY plane)and want to apply on the gas tank and I am literally struggling "How to" do it without distorting the badge details.

Blender File:
*Please find the dropbox link in the comment as the system is not allowing me to share the file since I need 10 reputations to post more than 2 links.*

[image: Side View]

[image: Top View]

Really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: Blender File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mna2syvmxv2hr8/HDGasTank.blend?dl=0

Comment: a curve deform could help. try converting a tank's profile (a line of edges) to a curve, then use the curve as modifier target. maybe you need two, an horizontal and a vertical deform...

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79509/how-to-add-detailed-engravings-onto-a-curved-surface-in-blender-for-3d-printing. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for sharing files on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I show how you can try using a curve deform:

[image]

you see three objects selected:

- a curve, converted from a tank profile strip of edges
- the original logo mesh (aside)
- the logo mesh deformed by the curve